# Release management Deployment Stage is timing out and the releases are in "In Progress" for ever

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, ms-release-management

We have used the trial version of Release Management and successfully deployed applications. But recently we faced an issue with the RM Clients not able to Pick up Team Projects and hence, could not create release templates for Release.

A lot of forums online suggested to update the RM components and we did that. But even with the latest components[12.0.30110.0], we cannot get it to deploy. The Deploy times out and the Status of the Release is "In Progress" for ever. unable to stop it or defer it.
If we try to switch back to the old version [12.0.21], the RM Server configuration step gives an error that the  RM.DB.cab does not have a valid Signature. But the file seems to have a valid Microsoft Signature.

We have a release planned today and very badly in need of help regarding this.
Appreciate any help with this.
Thanks in advance.
Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sandeep , i would suggest this

- option1-  Go to the deployment box and restart the release agent
- option 2 - Try debugging the agent , by running the agent in debug
  mode In Windows Services, stop the Microsoft Deployment Agent Service
  Run the DeploymentAgent.exe located in %Program Files(x86)%\
  Microsoft Visual studio 12.0\Release Management\bin with “debug”
  option from command line. (DeploymentAgent.exe debug start)

Running the agent in debug mode solved my problem.

Comment: please have a look at the log which i have posted. And thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Repairing the Client and restarting the machine did the trick. Thanks for giving the idea of debugging the services, without which we could not have cracked that the client alone has issues